# Is there any way to enforce android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha as white color

Tags: android, colors

Currently, my app is using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

I have a custom search view, which will display close button when there is text.

```
public class JStockSearchView extends LinearLayoutCompat {

    public JStockSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.jstock_search_view, this, true);

        mSearchSrcTextView = (JStockAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
        mCloseButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mCloseButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha));
```

However, the cross sign appears as black color.

[image]

Is there any way to enforce it to be white color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppCompat resources can change in future updates. You should put a close button in your resources and use that drawable instead.

If you want to make the current drawable white, then you can apply a `ColorFilter`. Example:

```
mCloseButton.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```

---

You can also apply a `ColorFilter` to the `Drawable`

```
Drawable closeDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha);
closeDrawable = closeDrawable.mutate(); // don't apply the ColorFilter everywhere
closeDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
mCloseButton.setImageDrawable(closeDrawable);
```

---

To use your own image, you can use the vector drawable import in Android Studio or get the image from [materialdesignicons.com](https://materialdesignicons.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forcing, try making a new color variable in colors.xml and assign it to the cross sign.

or

Download another cross icon from: https://design.google.com/icons/ (You can select white/black color here)